# $f(\frac{b}{12})$ exists?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, with the radius of convergence being $R>0$. Then if $f(b)$ exists, is $f(\frac{b}{12})$ exists? $b$ is just a random value.

Also, if$f(k)$ exists, for some $k $ in real numbers, $f(-k)$ exists?

Exist here means it is a possible value for the function.

I think $f(\frac{b}{2})$ exists, but not $f(-k)$. $f(\frac{b}{2})$ exists, because it is just a fraction of the $f(b)$, which already exists. But it's not always that $f(-k)$ exists, when $f(k)$ exists. because it is only the negative of the value.

Comment: google Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.... $b=0$ is trivial ... If $b\ne 0$ then $|b/12|<|b|\le R$ and the series $f(x)$ converges if $|x|<R.$

Comment: A typo:  at the start you talk of $\frac b{12}$ and at the end you talk of $\frac b2$.  I think the argument is the same in either case, but you should be consistent.

Comment: You are thinking about the right theorem.  I would look it up to make sure of the details.  For the first part, I would worry about whether we are guaranteed that the sum will diverge when $b \gt R$.  We are not guaranteed that it will converge, but that is different.  It could be that $b \gt R$ and the sum converges, but $\frac b{12} \gt R$ and the sum there diverges. You could have a power series from a recurrence with a small root and one at $b$. For the second, you are only negating half the terms, but $\log 2=\sum \frac {(-1)^n}n$ is a counterexample as the other sum is $\sum \frac 1n$